# No Referer in request headers from <video> tag request by android browser

Tags: android, html, video, http-headers, http-referer

For some business we have to check the request headers if is's **Referer** is original of some domain.

But we found there is no **Referer** in headers from **video** request by Android browser.

```
GET foo/bar/biz.mp4
HTTP/1.0
MAX-UDP-PORT: 65535
MTK-RTSP-CACHE-SIZE: 4
User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.1)
MTK-HTTP-CACHE-SIZE: 10
allow-cross-domain-redirect: false
MIN-UDP-PORT: 1024
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

How can I do to make headers contain **Referer**?

Answer (score 2):

add to `<head>` of your page

```
<meta name="referrer" content="always">
```

http://smerity.com/articles/2013/where_did_all_the_http_referrers_go.html